# Cannot connect to Protonmail Bridge SMTP (host machine) from a Docker container

Tags: docker, discourse

My setup is:

- Debian, Docker
- Host machine running Protonmail Bridge as a service
- Docker container running Discourse with their default recommended setup

Issue: From the Docker container, I cannot connect to the SMTP server exposed by the Protonmail Bridge on the host machine.

I checked open ports on the host machine, all good:

```
ss -plnt
State  Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address:Port  Peer Address:Port  Process
LISTEN   0      4096       127.0.0.1:1025      0.0.0.0:*    users:(("proton-bridge",pid=953,fd=12))
```

**How I test**

Host machine:
`openssl s_client -connect 127.0.01:1025 -starttls smtp`
Works.

Docker container:
`openssl s_client -connect 172.17.0.1:1025 -starttls smtp`
Connection refused.

I’m wondering if the Protonmail Bridge service that’s listening on `127.0.0.1:1025` is not accepting connections from the Docker container because they are not coming from `127.0.0.1` exactly? If this is the problem, how to validate and fix? If this is not the problem, what am I doing wrong?

**Other tests**

`nmap 127.0.0.1` on the host machine outputs:

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000010s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
1025/tcp open  NFS-or-IIS
1042/tcp open  afrog
```

Note that it lists the open port 1025.

`nmap 172.17.0.1` in the docker container does not output any 1025 port. I'm not sure if this is the problem either.

Output of `route` in the Docker container:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.17.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be impossible currently, but should be solved by [this pull request](https://github.com/ProtonMail/proton-bridge/pull/270).

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable compiling the `proton-bridge` package from source, you only have to change 1 line in the `internal/bridge/constants.go` file to say

```
Host = '127.0.0.1'
```

To

```
Host = '0.0.0.0'
```

Then recompile with `make build-nogui` (to build the "headless" version).

And you should be good to go!